# Pedir red social del cliente en el checkout de Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

llevo unos días peleando con este código y seguro que el fallo será una tontería. Quiero recoger en el los pedidos de Woocommerce una red social del cliente para segmentar el envío de la newsletter:
El código es muy sencillo y con un campo tipo TEXT funciona sin problema pero con el RADIO se muestra el campo pero no se guarda el valor ni se refleja en el perfil de usuario. Este es el código:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'jrc_add_user_field_to_checkout' );

function jrc_add_user_field_to_checkout( $checkout ) { 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $saved_rrss = $current_user->rrss;

    woocommerce_form_field('rrss', array(
            'type' => 'radio',        
            'class' => array('rrss form-row-wide'),        
            'label' => __('RR SS', 'jcode'),        
            'options' => array(
                    1 => __( 'Facebook', 'jcode' ),
                    2 => __( 'Instagram', 'jcode' ),
                    3 => __( 'Otro', 'jcode' ),
                ),
            'default' => '1',
            'required' => false
        ),
    $saved_rrss ); 
    
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'jrc_checkout_field_update_user_meta' );
  
function jrc_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id ) { 
    if ( $user_id && $_POST['rrss'] ) {
    // once again, use "rrss"       
       $args = array(
                    'ID' => $user_id,
                    'rrss' => esc_attr( $_POST['rrss'] )
            );      
           
        wp_update_user( $args );
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Nadie que controle de Woocommerce a ese nivel?

Comment: Por fin di con la clave. Dejo el código por si a alguien le vale:
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'jrc_custom_billing_fields');

function jrc_custom_billing_fields($fields)
{
  $fields['billing']['billing_rrss'] = array(
     'label' => __('RRSS', 'jrc'), 
     'required' => false, 
     'clear' => false, 
     'type' => 'radio', 
     'class' => array('rrss'),   
     'options' => array(
        'Facebook' => __( 'Facebook', 'jrc' ),
        'Instagram' => __( 'Instagram', 'jrc' ),
        'Twitter' => __( 'Twitter', 'jrc' ),
     )
  );
    return $fields;
}